# Docker: does using FROM execute the entire base image?

Tags: docker

Supposing I have a base image that does some execution of it's own: does including this using the

```
FROM: image:version
```

run all the commands in the original Dockerfile? I.e. even things like RUN, ADD, etc .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The `FROM` command uses that `image:version` as the parent image (the pre-built snapshot of the file system). Your commands are then run on top of that.

However if the parent Dockerfile has [`ONBUILD RUN`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#onbuild) statements, those will be RUN as if they were present at the very top of your Dockerfile.
Please see [the Dockerfile docs](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#from)

Comment: Just to clarify: so if the parent image itself has operations that it does they need to re-run in the child? It isnt really a form on inheritance then?

Comment: The ADD, RUN, etc commands needed to create the parent are not run *again*... but the results of those directives are stored in the parent image

Comment: with the expection of the [`ONBUILD RUN`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#onbuild) statements which would be run as if they were at the very top of your Dockerfile